# Graphhopper as a background service on ubuntu

Tags: graphhopper

I want to run graphhopper as a background service and have it start on boot. I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Search how to create a service from any java application http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm

Comment: I prefer the (bash) script version with 'nohup java -jar some.jar &' then put this into in a shell script and put that in the crontab with a '@reboot' statement. But I'm by no means a scripting/linux expert on this matter.

Comment: Ah, the link also mention 'nohup' but it was replaced by 'setsid' ... see also other java applications and how they do this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/rpm/src/main/packaging/init.d/elasticsearch ... they seem to use 'daemon' for this task http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon but this needs explicit installation on major linux distros